# Detect application stop in Vaadin 6

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I have problem in my web application written in Vaadin 6 (application runs in Apache Tomcat 6.x).

The problem is that I need to detect when someone stops application in Tomcat manager - I need to perform some steps before stopping. How can I detect that? Is it even possible? I have tried to detect this with Application.close(), but it does not work..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to listen for a contextDestroyed event.

If you are using the Spring integration for Vaadin, you can also use a simple lifecycle listener bean to track events you need to react to.